# Pycharm lose object indicator after put and get from queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, queue

I know this is not a major issue. But when my object has many variables and each of them is very long, it becomes annoying. Is there any way that can make Python/Pycharm know that `cur` is a `Cat` type? Like type casting? Writing function that create a new object and copy every variable looks unnecessary...

```
from queue import Queue


class Cat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'cat'


q = Queue()
c = Cat()
q.put(c)

cur = q.get()

print(cur.name)    <= No 'name' indicator shows up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable with type annotations, `q` could be annotated as a queue with cats:

```
q = Queue()  # type: Queue[Cat]
```

or

```
q: Queue[Cat] = Queue()
```

Answer (score -1):

in python at least. You cannot access a variable from within a class while outside of it unless you use global in your case you could use something like this.

```
from queue import Queue

class Cat:
     def __init__(self):
             self.name = 'cat'

// Find variable
global name
// Your code can go here this can just be a check to see if it has functioned correctly
print(name)
```

Hopefully this works :)